# How to find the sum of a multidimensional associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to sum the values of a multidimensional associative array?

My array is as follows:

```
$testarray=[];
$testarray[]=[
    "2019-12-31" => [
        "category1" => [
            "total" => "10"
            ],
        "category2" => [
            "total" => "20"
            ],
        ],
    "2020-01-31" => [
        "category1" => [
            "total" => "100"
            ],
        "category2" => [
            "total" => "200"
            ],
        ],
    "2020-02-28" => [
        "category1" =>  [
            "total" => "1000"
            ],
        "category2" => [
            "total" => "2000"
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

I tried the following:

```
foreach($testarray[0] as $Offset=>$ArrayOfResults){
    foreach($ArrayOfResults as $ResultOffset=>$Result){
        $total+= $Result["total"];
    }
    $sums[$Offset]=$total;
}
```

The result is :

```
"2019-12-31" => 30
"2020-01-31" => 330
"2020-02-28" => 3330
```

How do i get the desired result as follows adding up category1 and category2 values:

```
"2019-12-31" => 30
"2020-01-31" => 300
"2020-02-28" => 3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nested loops, use `array_sum()` and `array_column()`.

```
foreach ($testarray[0] as $date => $results) {
    $sums[$date] = array_sum(array_column($results, 'total'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to reset `$total` each iteration:

```
foreach($testarray[0] as $Offset=>$ArrayOfResults){ 
    $total = 0;
    foreach($ArrayOfResults as $ResultOffset=>$Result){
        $total+= $Result["total"];
    }
    $sums[$Offset]=$total;
}
```